# Why Jupyter can't read the .csv file?

Tags: python, csv, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I'm using python 3 in jupyter notebook. The problem is that it can't read the csv file. The command to read the csv file i have used is:

```
  import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("py.csv")
df
```

I have tried a lot of other ways too, but every time it says that , file is not found although the csv file in my pc.

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-cc06427474dd> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
      2 
----> 3 df = pd.read_csv("py.csv")
      4 df

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    654 
--> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    656 
    657     parser_f.__name__ = name

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    403 
    404     # Create the parser.
--> 405     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    406 
    407     if chunksize or iterator:

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    762             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
    763 
--> 764         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    765 
    766     def close(self):

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
    983     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
    984         if engine == 'c':
--> 985             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
    986         else:
    987             if engine == 'python':

~/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1603         kwds['allow_leading_cols'] = self.index_col is not False
   1604 
-> 1605         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1606 
   1607         # XXX

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:4209)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:8873)()

FileNotFoundError: File b'py.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: " file is not found although the csv file in my pc." ... have you tried passing it the full path? Otherwise, it will check in the current working directory.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? I'm new in programming so I haven't understood

Comment: What is the location of the file in your file system?

Comment: it's  in the desktop and i'm using Mac

Comment: OK, then try using `'~/Desktop/py.csv'`

Comment: It works . Thanks  :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use something like this

```
pd.read_csv('C:\Users\user\Desktop\Workbook1.csv')
```

Currently you are not mentioning the path to the file so it is looking in the current working directory where the file is not present.

Either put the whole path or put your file in the working directory
Hope it helps!

Comment: I used  '~/Desktop/py.csv' and it works now  thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You are using the right command. But specify the path for the file. If you are using Jupyter notebook than add the file py.csv to folder where your jupyter code is placed. Then it should identify the file and no longer should the error exist.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you file is in the working directory and then try the below code

import pandas first :

```
import pandas as pd
```

Read the csv file :

```
mydata = pd.read_csv("mydata.csv")
```

my data will be your data frame name and my `data.csv` is the file name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to import os and then you will be able to see the current working directory like:

```
import os
```

`os.getcwd()` # will provide the current working directory

Now you can change the working directory to your current folder by specifying the path

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop')
```

then you can simply tread the file from the current working directory

```
df = pd.read_csv("py.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found out that if your .csv file is using a different delimiter/separator other than a comma, you need to specify a separator parameter like the following

```
pd.read_csv('py.csv', sep='|')
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add full path after import pandas.

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('d:/Attendance-Import.csv')
df
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a quick solution. when you import the file, you must add another '/'.

Example: pd.read_csv('c:/drive/py.csv'), then you put this pd.read_csv('c://drive//py.csv').